# Problem with pushing multiple view controllers in one code block

Tags: objective-c

In order to restore my iphone application to a paticular view controller, i am trying to push the view controllers one after another in the application delegate.

The order of the view controllers on the stack initially is : 
1. Root View Controller
2. First View Controller
3. Second View Controller

What I want is that when my application launches, it should go directly to the Second view controller. For this I have written the following code :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO]; 

FirstViewController *firstViewController=[[NSClassFromString(@"FirstViewController") alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:NO];

SecondViewController *secondViewController=[[NSClassFromString(@"SecondViewController") alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:NO];
```

The problem is that when the Second view controller loads, its back button is named "Back" , instead of the title of the first view controller. I have not explicitly set a back button in the third view controller.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should set the title of the UINvaigationItem for FirstViewController, which will be aditionally seen in  the center of navigation bar.